# this code to find the largest element in an array in nasm does not work

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section .bss
digit0: resb 2
digit1: resb 1
answer1 : resb 1
answer2 : resb 1
answer : resw 1
array: resb 50
element: resb 1

num: resb 1

temp: resb 1

largest: resb 1

smallest: resb 1

count: resb 1

section .data

msg1: db "Enter the number of elements : "

size1: equ $-msg1

newline: db 0Ah
msg2 : db "enter a number:"
size2 : equ $-msg2

len2: equ $ - newline

 section .text

global _start

_start:

 mov byte[count], 0

;Printing the message to enter the number

mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, msg1

mov edx, size1

int 80h



mov eax,3

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,digit1

mov edx,1

int 80h



mov eax,3

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,digit0

mov edx,1

int 80h



mov eax,3

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,temp

mov edx,1

int 80h


sub byte[digit1], 30h

sub byte[digit0], 30h

mov al, byte [digit1]

mov bl, 10

mul bl

add al, byte[digit0]

add byte[num], al

mov al, byte[num]


mov byte[temp], al

mov ebp, array


reading:

mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1



mov ecx, msg2

mov edx, size2

int 80h



mov eax,3

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,digit1

mov edx,1

int 80h



mov eax,3

mov ebx,0

mov ecx,digit0

mov edx,2

int 80h

sub byte[digit1], 30h

sub byte[digit0], 30h



mov al, byte [digit1]


mov bl, 10

mul bl

add al,byte[digit0]



mov byte[ebp], al 

add ebp, 1

dec byte[temp]

cmp byte[temp], 0

jg reading



mov ebp, array

mov al,byte[ebp]



mov byte[largest],al

mov byte[smallest],al

add ebp, 1



searching:

mov al, byte[largest]

cmp al, byte[ebp]

jnb if

mov al, byte[smallest]

cmp al, byte[ebp]

jna else

add byte[count], 1


add ebp, 1
mov al, byte[count]


cmp al, byte[num]

jb searching


mov al,byte[largest]



mov bl, 10

div bl

add ah, 30h


add al, 30h



mov byte[answer1], ah

mov byte[answer2], al



mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1


mov ecx, answer2

mov edx, 1

int 80h


mov eax, 4

mov ebx, 1

mov ecx, answer1

mov edx, 1

int 80h



mov eax, 4          

mov ebx, 1          

mov ecx, newline      


mov edx, len2     

int 80h

mov eax, 1

mov ebx, 0

int 80h


if:

mov al, byte[ebp]

mov byte[largest],al 

add byte[count], 1

add ebp, 1

jmp searching



else:

mov al, byte[ebp]

mov byte[smallest], al

add byte[count], 1

add ebp, 1

jmp searching
```

Comment: msg2 is defined as "enter the number"

Comment: Use debugger to analyze what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mov al,byte[largest]
mov bl, 10

div bl      ;PROBLEM IS HERE
add ah, 30h
add al, 30h
```

In this part you are forgetting to clear the AH register prior to doing the `div bl`. Remember that a byte division use AX.

```
movzx ax,byte[largest]
mov   bl,10
div   bl
add   ah,30h
add   al,30h
```